# Check if void* points to a specific class object

Tags: c++, linux

I have the following code in my homework:

```
mmapedData node(size);
void* p = mmap(NULL, size + sizeof(mmapedData), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, 
-1, 0); 
memcpy(p, (void*)&nodecpy, sizeof(mmapedData));
```

What is the right way to check if the first sizeof(mmapedData) bytes of the memory block pointed by p contains a object of mmapedData class (c++)?

thanks.

Comment: It's impossible. (Unless you add some constraints. E.g, maybe `mmapedData` is polymorphic, and `p` always points a polymorphic class that shares a common base with `mmapedData`, and no multiple inheritance is involved?)

Comment: @GuyBerkovitz tell your teacher C++ and C are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do that in standard C or C++.

Comment: Should be: _There is no way to do that in C and C++_. :)